# Problema adaptando imagen con texto "sticky" a punto de vista del celular usando html y css

Tags: html, css

la idea es tener la imagen del lado izquierdo y el texto sticky del lado derecho dividiendo la pantalla a la mitad y al moverlo a formato celular que la imagen este por encima del texto pero no consigo que la imagen aparezca, solo el texto, este es mi primer sitio web asi que aun no entiendo algunas cosas del css, a continuación les dejo el código que estoy usando en css (tener en cuenta que ambas etiquetas left y right estan dentro de la etiqueta section):

html:

```
<section>
    {% if gorrv == "Naruto" and x.gorra == "Naruto" %}
    <div class="left">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="bg">
                {% if dobi == True %}
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img style="width: 700px; height: 700px;" src="/static/gorras_ver/gorra1A.png">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img style="width: 700px; height: 700px;" src="/static/gorras_ver/gorra1B.png">
                {% endif %}
                {% if dobi == False %}
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img style="width: 700px; height: 700px;" src="/static/gorras_ver/gorra1G.png">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <img style="width: 700px; height: 700px;" src="/static/gorras_ver/gorra1H.png">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="inner sticky">
            <h2 class="display-4 text-center mt-4 titulo">Gorra: {{x.gorra}}</h2>
            <h2>- Color: Negro con detalles naranja</h2>
            <h2>- Ajustable</h2>
            {% if dobi == True %}
            <h2>- En inventario: {{x.stockd}}</h2>
            {% endif %}
            {% if dobi == False %}
            <h2>- En inventario: {{x.stock}}</h2>
            {% endif %}
            <h2>- {{x.precio}}$</h2>
            <div class="boton-cen">
                <form action="/ver-dob/{{x.gorra}}">
                    <button style="margin-right: 25px;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-lg btn-primary"> <!-- btn-block hace que el boton ocupe todo el ancho -->
                        Doblada
                    </button>
                </form>
                <form action="/ver-rec/{{x.gorra}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"> <!-- btn-block hace que el boton ocupe todo el ancho -->
                        Recta
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            {% if dobi == True %}

            {% if x.stockd == 0 %}
            <h2>Esta gorra en este estilo ya no esta disponible</h2>
            {% endif %}

            <form action="/carro-add-dob/{{x.gorra}}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input style="width: 150px;" type="number" name="cant" placeholder="Cantidad" min="1" max="{{x.stockd}}" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cantidad?')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <br>
            <div class="boton-cen">
                    <button style="margin-right: 25px;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-lg btn-primary"> <!-- btn-block hace que el boton ocupe todo el ancho -->
                        Añadir al carro y volver
                    </button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
            {% if dobi == False %}

            {% if x.stock == 0 %}
            <h2>Esta gorra en este estilo ya no esta disponible</h2>
            {% endif %}

            <form action="/carro-add-rect/{{x.gorra}}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input style="width: 150px;" type="number" name="cant" placeholder="Cantidad" min="1" max="{{x.stock}}" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cantidad?')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <br>
            <div class="boton-cen">
                    <button style="margin-right: 25px;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-lg btn-primary"> <!-- btn-block hace que el boton ocupe todo el ancho -->
                        Añadir al carro y volver
                    </button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
                <br>
                <form action="/volver-casa">
                    <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-lg btn-primary"> <!-- btn-block hace que el boton ocupe todo el ancho -->
                        Home
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

hay mas del codigo html pero basicamente es lo mismo con diferentes "if" por eso no lo incluyo

css:

```
section {
    display: flex;
}
.left,
.right {
    flex: 50%;
}
.right .inner.sticky {
    padding: 40px 100px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 952px){

}
```

la idea de la ultima parte es adaptar el texto y las imágenes para que primero aparezcan las imágenes y luego el texto, en lugar de dividir la pantalla que aparezcan una y luego la otra

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: si el problema que esta todo desordenado, la verdad me gustaria configurar tu codigo pero esta todo desordenado, y tienes que trabajar responsive para que adapte al celular